# Maximum time that an explicit wait can wait in selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver, synchronization, wait

My scenario is to wait for a particular element. It might take 2,3,4,5 days.
Can that be achieved using explicit wait or fluent wait?
If not what can be the maximum time we can give for explicit wait or fluent wait?

Answer (score 0):

Use below code :-

```
int MINUTES = 1; // The delay in minutes
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() { // Function runs every MINUTES minutes.
                YOURFUNCTIONNAME();
            }
        }, 0, 1000 * 60 * MINUTES);
```

Add the time as per your requirement